# GLWpfControl and OpenTK force graphics adapter

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am using GLWpfControl and OpenTK for a Game that I'm developing. The game has a lobby which runs on WPF and C# and I used GLWpfControl for the OpenGL stuff. The problem lies on my laptop that has two graphics cards, one Intel and one NVidia. The Intel draws nothing on the display for OpenGL, probably compatibility issues. Although I modified the source code of GLWpfControl to use DirectX 11 instead of 9 that binds to a D3DImage and further to WPF, so I can always select the NVidia graphics card, the OpenGL (OpenTK) part selects the primary adapter which is the intel card and as I said earlier I get a dark background and nothing renders on the screen. So here comes my question, since I found nothing online, is there a way to force OpenTK to use my NVidia card or the dedicated adapter? For OpenGL and C++ there are solutions online but not for C# and OpenTK.

**EDIT** :
There is a property in the GLWpfControlSettings called ContextToUse. Has anyone used it, or knows how to use it to get the desired adapter?

**EDIT-2** :
I found this link : [exporting-data-symbols-in-c-for-nvidia-optimus](http://lucasmagder.com/blog/2014/05/exporting-data-symbols-in-c-for-nvidia-optimus/) which works on his .NET Framework example but not under WPF and .Net 7.0. Anyone knows why?